# CakePHP Form Helper just generated too much code for me

Tags: cakephp

I am using cakePHP.
I used the cakePHP built-in Form Helper to generate an input text box:

```
echo $form->input('quote', array('label'=>'Post Number', 'class'=>''));
```

But when I looked at the HTML source code, I found out these:

```
<div class="input text">
<label for="ReplyQuote">Post Number</label>
<input name="data[Reply][quote]" type="text" class="" maxlength="12" value="1" id="ReplyQuote" />
</div>
```

It's really more than enough. I mean the code generated by the Cake built-in Form Helper.
Those DIV tags with class named in a strange naming convention way are not helpful,
because there is space in between the Class name like:

```
 <div class="input text">
```

Does CakePHP have any options for users to omit those DIV Tags?

Comment: You're aware you can assign multiple classes to a single HTML element, right? This can be very handy for, say, assigning standard styles to all types of input fields, but also having specific style rules for text inputs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

Check out the options array that you can pass to the FormHelper::input() method.  Book reference is at http://book.cakephp.org/view/189/Automagic-Form-Elements

In short, the form helper is adding two distinct classes to the div -- input, and text.  If you don't want a div, just do:

```
echo $form->input( 'quote', array( 'label' => 'Post Number', 'div' => false ) );
```

Setting the options['class'] value only affects the class selector assigned to the actual input itself (see in your HTML code how the input tag has class=""?)

Comment: Thank you for the quick help, Travis Leleu

Comment: It should be noted that disabling the `div` option also breaks the automatic error-messages and labels, meaning you'll have to invoke `FormHelper::label` and `FormHelper::error` yourself if you want to incorporate those elements.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use $form->text() for input box.